# error using --force in git

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made an error with an earlier `rails generate`, (I forgot to add content string, etc) and then I corrected it, and am adding the right details, and now I need to push through the new changes. What command do I need to use to use `--force`?

```
Another migration is already named create_statuses: //Documents/rails_projects/treebook/db/migrate/20130803211355_create_statuses.rb. Use --force to remove the old migration file and replace it.
$ --force rails generate scaffold status name:string content:text
-bash: --force: command not found
$ rails --force generate scaffold status name:string content:text
Error: Command '--force' not recognized
Usage: rails COMMAND [ARGS]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just destroy the old migration and all the files it created:

```
$ rails destroy scaffold Status name:string content:text
```

Then you can run a new migration.

If you make a mistake with a migration, you don't need to destroy it entirely.  You can run other migrations to add columns, change names, etc.  However, if you are a newbie and using scaffolding, it is probably easiest to just destroy the incorrect migration and create a new one.

Comment: on destroy you can call `rails destroy scaffold Status` without attributes.

Comment: but before destroying a scaffold be sure to rollback it's migration otherwise you'll have to delete statuses table on your own in mysq or whatever db you use.